# Java: how to wrap all elements with <sometag> in org.w3c.dom?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom, xpath

My goal is to wrap every single dom elements (`Node.ELEMENT_NODE`) on current `org.w3c.dom.Document` with tag `<something style="background-color:red"></something>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    org.w3c.dom.DOMDocument doc;
    paintAllNodes(doc, 0);
}

public static void paintAllNodes(Node node, int level) {
    // Process node

    // If there are any children, visit each one
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
        // Get child node
        Node childNode = list.item(i);        

        // Visit child node
        paintAllNodes(childNode, level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you want to add the attribute `style` to all of the elements or also to change the name of the elements?

Comment: I want to wrap `<something style="background-color:red'"></something>` around all elements.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest and simplest solution for this problem. Remember to add XSLT to your tool-set as *the* tool for any XML transformation. :)

Comment: Why not award your bounty to your favourite answer? Is there any reason for that? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to propose you a recursive solution, which make use of `Node#replaceChild` method to replace a node with a new tag:

```
public static void paintAllNodes(Node node) {
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element somethingElement = node.getOwnerDocument().createElement("something");
        somethingElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red");
        node.getParentNode().replaceChild(somethingElement, node);
        somethingElement.appendChild(node);
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            paintAllNodes(nodeList.item(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new File("document.xml"));
    paintAllNodes(document.getDocumentElement());

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

I've tested it with this xml:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div>test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My main has printed out this new xml, which seems to be what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><something style="background-color:red"><html>
    <something style="background-color:red"><head>
        <something style="background-color:red"><title>title</title></something>
    </head></something>
    <something style="background-color:red"><body>
    <something style="background-color:red"><h1>title</h1></something>
    <something style="background-color:red"><div>test</div></something>
    </body></something>
</html></something>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get nullexception at ` Element somethingElement = node.getOwnerDocument().createElement("something");`

Comment: Have you used my main method? At the first time you have to pass to `paintAllNodes` the `document.getDocumentElement()`: `paintAllNodes(document.getDocumentElement());`. Have you done that?

Comment: I have made an update to the question. I have used your codes.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I've changed a few lines of code to make it more reliable. The `getOwnerDocument()` method returns null if node is a Document or DocumentType. Now you can also pass the whole `Document` to the `paintAllNodes` method.  Can you try it please?

Comment: Yeah, I've run the new code but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried printing out some text inside the for bracket, but it wasn't being printed out.

Comment: Kim, I'm sorry, I've corrected the last code. It wasn't doing anything :-) You just have to replace `paintAllNodes(document);` with `paintAllNodes(document.getDocumentElement());`. However, if it still doesn't works for you, it would be very useful to see your xml...

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo, thank you very much for accepting my answer. So does it work, at last? :-)

Answer (score 11):

**One of the simplest ways to solve such kind of problems (as for any XML transformation) is by using XSLT**.

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
 <something style="background-color:red">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </something>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document, for example this one:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<something style="background-color:red">
   <nums>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>01</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>02</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>03</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>04</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>05</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>06</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>07</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>08</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>09</num>
      </something>
      <something style="background-color:red">
         <num>10</num>
      </something>
   </nums>
</something>
```

**Note**: It is left as an exercise to the reader how to initiate an XSLT transformation in Java code :)

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks, it would really be good if an XSLT answer gets the bounty for this question -- some people need to understand which is the best tool to use for transforming XML :)

Answer (score 6):

This will wrap every `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` in a `org.w3c.dom.Document` with a `<something>` tag:

```
public static void paintAllNodes(Document doc) {
    // build list of Node.ELEMENT_NODE to process
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            nodes.add(node);
        }
    }

    // iterate through each node and wrap with <something> tag
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        // remember the next sibling for inserting at end
        Node nextSibling = node.getNextSibling();

        // remember the parent and remove this node from it
        Node parent = node.getParentNode();
        parent.removeChild(node);

        // create <something> element and attach node
        Element element = doc.createElement("something");
        NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("style");
        attr.setNodeValue("background-color:red");
        attributes.setNamedItem(attr);
        element.appendChild(node);

        // insert new element where the node was 
        parent.insertBefore(element, nextSibling);
    }
}
```

If you want to exclude any nodes then just filter them out in the first `for` loop.

Comment: this just returns a blank document. it wipes out the loaded DOM document.

Comment: Can you give an example of a document you're dealing with? I tested with this and the above code works fine: `<html><body><h1>Test Header</h1><p>Test body</p></body></html>`

Comment: +1 for the use of `doc.getElementsByTagName("*");` to avoid recursion.

Comment: I've tested it, it works! I've also added my answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a non-answer ;-) I propose to use CSS... `something {background:red}` 
Obviously, this only makes sense if you use CSS anyways.

Answer (score -1):

For any given node 'node', and the document 'document' it came from something like this should work.

```
Node parent = node.getParent();
Node nextSibling = node.getNextSibling();

parent.removeChild(node);

Element something = document.createElement("something");
NamedNodeMap atts = something.getAttributes();
Attr att = document.createAttribute("style");
att.setNodeValue("background-color:red;");
atts.setNamedItem(att);
something.addChild(node);
parent.insertBefore(something, nextSibling);
```